# Install Sentence-Transformers as a Workspace package on Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: python, apache-spark, pip, azure-synapse, sentence-transformers

I'm trying to install sentence-transformers python package as a workspace package for Azure Synapse Analytics.(To be used on Apache Spark Pool)

Tried installing it through magic command `%pip install sentence-transformers` through a notebook and it works.

Following the steps for uploading the `sentence-transformers-2.2.2.tar.gz` to Workspace and configuration throws the following error mentioned in the screenshot.

I tested with couple of other python packages and they work fine.

Any workarounds?

[image]

Comment: Do you have Storage Blob Data Contributor on your ADLS gen2 Storage account?

Comment: Yes. I'm having the Storage Blob Data Contributor access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same error when I tried to upload the `sentence-transformers-2.2.2.tar.gz` from workspace packages to spark pool.

[image]

I am able to install the above package using the below workaround.

First I have created a `requirements.txt` file with package and version like below.

`sentence-transformers==2.2.2`

[image]

I got this error when trying to import before installing the package.

[image]

Upload the `requirements.txt` file to spark pool packages like below.

[image]

Wait for the Job to get succeed.

[image]

Now, you can see I am able to import it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update from product team:** Currently, we are working on fix on improve this error message and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-pool-packages#manage-packages-from-synapse-studio-or-azure-portal) with the changes.

> The file `.tar.gz`  format is only for **R language packages** (and not for python). To install python packages please use `.yml` or `.whl` file formats.

For more details,refer to thread on MS Q&A platform:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1254671/install-sentence-transformers-as-a-workspace-packa

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. Will stick to uploading the requirements.txt file at the moment, which solves the issue.